# How RewriteCond test the Useragent

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I try to block some bots using RewriteEngine and htaccess. For `DotBot` and similar bots I found many scripts like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DotBot 
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

I understand everything with one exemption: Why most sites use `^DotBot` instead of `DotBot` . I'm aware, `^` is the beginning of a string. In my logs, I found always user agents like:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; DotBot/1.1; http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/dotbot, help@moz.com)
```

Use RewriteCond the whole string for testing? In my case, I think so. Only

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} DotBot
```

works well. But have on my managed systems no way to test it directly. `DotBot` is a very short identifier and I try to block not the wrong agents.

Mario

Comment: _“But have on my managed systems no way to test it directly.”_ - there’s plenty of browser extensions that allow you to change the UA your own browser sends, so if you need to test any such setups, you can do it quite easily this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following; this is looking for string `bot` using ignore case option(since we can't be sure what else could be there with word bot so why not only look only string `bot` here), based on your shown samples/examples only and let me know if this helps you(I couldn't test it).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bot [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Comment: The solution works like expected. Now I realize with my log file the correct http-Status for all requests. So I think on some days the bot is going to request only the start page.

Comment: @Mario, awesome, happy to help, thanks for getting back here.

Answer (score 0):

Using a browser extension let me find an effective condition:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(DotBot|YandexBot|AhrefsBot|MegaIndex|SEOkicks|MJ12bot).*$
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

It works in the root directory. But all files into subdirectories are still ignored. I have no idea, which RewriteRule all content in the active directory and all subdirectories applies?!

Comment: How about changing your condition to `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (DotBot|YandexBot|AhrefsBot|MegaIndex|SEOkicks|MJ12bot) [NC]` only this one? Sorry I couldn't test it since I don't have that extension with me, but this could be more helpful from regex perspective, let me know if this helps you?